# bootstrap switch checking checked status always returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I don't want to listen for the event of the switch being toggled, instead I want to use JavaScript to check it's current checked state.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pushtoggle" state="true" data-role="none">
```

I have this simple JavaScript to check the checked value:

```
if ($('#pushtoggle').is(':checked')){ alert('checked'); } else { alert('not checked');}
```

No matter which state (on or off) the switch is set to I always get the alert that it is not checked.

I initialized the toggle switch using:

```
$("[name='pushtoggle']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

I also tried setting the checked attribute within the input tag.  Nothing works to get me the correct state of the switch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have any element with id = `pushtoggle` but you're using an id selector.

Try with this

```
if ($('[name="pushtoggle"]').is(':checked')){ 
  alert('checked'); 
} 
else { 
  alert('not checked');
}
```

Comment: Wow, stupid mistake on my part... changed name to id and it worked.  Thanks Claudio.

Comment: This one works with BS 5, the others don't work

Answer (score 5):

```
$("[name='pushtoggle']").bootstrapSwitch('state')
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution is good for setting too. `$('#mySwitch').attr('checked', true);` does nothing, `.bootstrapSwitch('state',true)` does.